# Google Chrome Extension - Use data from extension.js file in content_script.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Okay, so first off I should probably define what I mean by `extension.js` and `content_script.js`:

- `extension.js` - The script that is used in the extension popup...  e.g: if I were to click a button in the extension popup, I could use `extension.js` to do something with that.  extension.js` does not effect the page you're viewing, it only effects the popup box.
- `content_script.js` -  this "[content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)" is what is effects the current webpage, in this case it's JavaScript.  But this script cannot affect the popup, it can only affect the webpage you've told it to.

---

Okay, the question is basically the title.  How do you use data from `extension.js` in `content_script.js`...  Let me give an example:

Say I have a form in the popup, it has a some text fields...  lets say one has the ID of `exmp`,  now, we could fetch this with `extension.js`, but how would we feed it to `content_script.js` so it could modify the webpage.

`extension.js`

```
var exmp = document.getElementById("exmp"); // from popup.html
```

`content_script.js`

```
// How would I fetch the "exmp" variable from extension.js?
if (exmp.value == "test text") {
   // Do stuff that modifies the web page.
}
```

---

Regarding answers:

- jQuery is acceptable.  But answers with pure JavaScript are preferred.  Answers that use both are even better.
- Sources will to Chrome Extension will be listed at the end of the question (below).

---

Sources:

- [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview)
- [Overview - Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#contentScripts)
- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following functions to communicate (Bidirectionally) between content and background scripts

```
window.chrome.runtime.sendMessage() 
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {});
```

Further to your question, from memory you can put the following in your background script

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {

  if(msg == 'GetData'){
    sendResponse(SomeData);
  }

});
```

And use the following in your content script

```
window.chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'msg':'GetData'},function(response){    
  // How would I fetch the "exmp" variable from extension.js?
  if (response.value == "test text") {
     // Do stuff that modifies the web page.
  }
});
```